# cd command not working with execvp

Tags: c, linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *ip;
    char *temp[10];
    pid_t pid;

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        int i = 0;

        do {
            gets(ip);

            temp[0] = strtok(ip, " ");
            while (temp[++i] != NULL) {
                temp[i] = strtok(NULL," ");
            }

            pid_t pid2;

            pid2 = fork();
            if (pid2 == 0) {
                execvp(temp[0], temp);
            }
        } while(strcmp(temp[0], "quit"));

        if (!strcmp(temp[0],"quit")) {
            return;
        }
    } else if (pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"error in creating child");
    } else if (pid > 0) {
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

this code doesnt seem to work with cd command.how do i go about fixing it?i am fairly new to the concepts of OS and any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: "`int main()` and indentation or GTFO!" - "But I..." - "`int main()` and indentation or GTFO!"

Comment: @H2CO3: `int main(void)` or GTFO!

Comment: `char *ip;` -- `ip` is a garbage pointer; you don't allocate anything for it to point to. `gets(ip);` -- Even if `ip` pointed to a properly allocated array of `char`, the `gets` function is inherently unsafe; it's even been removed from the language as of 2011. Use `fgets` instead (which requires a little more work).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`cd` does not exist as an executable command. (And it cannot, because a process can only change the working directory of itself, not of its parent.) You will need to implement `cd` yourself as a builtin, using the `chdir()` system call, similar to the way you've already implemented `quit`.

Other commands you will need to implement as builtins as well, if you plan to implement them, include (for example, I'm not trying to be thorough):

- `pushd` and `popd`
- `exit`, `logout`, `bye`, etc
- `fg`, `bg`, `jobs`, and the `&` suffix
- `history`
- `set`, `unset,` `export`

Comment: okay in that case i need to use chdir outside the child in the parent right? how do i go back inside the loop then?

Comment: You'll need to restructure the loop a bit. Try writing a function that processes and runs one command. It may simplify things to use the `exit()` system call instead of trying to break out of the loop.

Comment: Also, the `fork()` call should be immediately before `execvp()`. Don't put it any earlier.