# Execvp command not working with "type" command

Tags: c, linux, shell

I've been trying to execute the "type" command with execve funtion in C

```
char *arg[] ={
    "type",
    "type",
    NULL
};
   execvp("type", arg);
```

Here is the code that i've been using but it returns me -1
I've tried approximatively the same code for echo command , it working perfectly

Any help please?

Comment: Check `errno` with `perror`.

Comment: `type` on UNIX is built into bash, not an external command, so it's not _expected_ that you can run it this way.

Comment: ...the external-command equivalent is `which`.

Comment: Awfully close to a dupe:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686114/cd-command-not-working-with-execvp

Comment: @AndrewHenle, ...very close to be sure, but I think there's an argument to distinguish what kinds of answers are applicable to each insofar as `cd` (like other commands listed in the linked question's answer) is something where there's almost no value at all to invoking it as a subprocess (that answer lists commands that modify or reflect shell state), but `type` has a use distinct from modifying process state.

Comment: ...granted, that argument only goes so far, as a noninteractive shell won't have most functions/aliases/etc loaded, so `type` in it will add very little value over `which` (not zero value -- it'll pick up configuration from `BASH_ENV`, or functions exported in the environment -- but still, only very little).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal and expected behavior: `type` is a shell builtin, not an external command; only external commands can be invoked with `execv`-family syscalls.

You could invoke a shell, and have *that shell* run `type`:

```c
/* cmd should be the command you want to check 'type' output for */
char *args[] = { "bash", "-c", "type $@", "bash", cmd, NULL };
```

...or you could use `which` instead (which is generally less capable, but the extra capabilities `type` adds in bash are things that intrinsically require a shell).

Comment: It worked , thanks you very much , just a small correction , the type and cmd work when i put them in the same bracket

Comment: @mlakhssa, yes, `"type type"` would work, but the point of doing it the way shown here is to be able to run `type` against _any_ command without creating security bugs.

Comment: @mlakhssa, ...think about what happens if someone told your C program it wanted to have the type of `$(rm -rf ~)`. You don't want `bash -c 'type $(rm -rf ~)'` to wipe out all your files! That's why the _safe_ thing is (C equivalent to) `bash -c 'type "$@"' '$(rm -rf ~)'`, which will properly throw an error message instead of running the hostile command.

Comment: I understand the issue here, but i don't know why bash -c 'type "$@"' 'ls' for example does not work but bash -c 'type ls" is working, any idea why?

Comment: @mlakhssa, the problem there is `$0` not being filled in (or used). `"$@"` only includes `$1` and onward. I've edited to address that issue; making the given C equivalent to `bash -c 'type "$@"' 'bash' 'ls'` (it's also conventional to use `_` as a `$0` placeholder, but using `bash` makes for better error messages since one gets `bash: something failed` instead of `_: something failed`).